# Taking more than one method to route in laravel

Tags: laravel, methods, routes, controller, laravel-8

So, i'm doing a form where i want to take more than one method from my controller to the same Route in Laravel 8.

Is it possible?
Because i've been searching but all the answers i see for that is for the older versions where the routings where a bit different.

I tried to adapt like this but i see that i am doing it wrong :/

```
Route::post('/editProfile', [
    'avatar' => [UserController::class, 'updateAvatar'],
    'bgImage' => [UserController::class, 'updateBGImage'],
]);
```

In the UserController i have:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function profile(){
        return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()));

    }

    

    public function updateAvatar(Request $request) {
        
        //Handle the user upload of the avatar
        if($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('uploads/avatars/' . $filename));

            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->avatar = $filename;
            $user->save();

        }
        return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()));
    }

    public function editProfile(){
        return view('editProfile', array('user' => Auth::user()));

    }

    public function updateBGImage(Request $request) {
        
        //Handle the user upload of the avatar
        if($request->hasFile('bgImage')) {
            $bgImage = $request->file('bgImage');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $bgImage->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($bgImage)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('uploads/bgImages/' . $filename));

            $user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);
            $user->bgImage = $filename;
            $user->save();

        }
        return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While there are many ways you could tackle this, I think the cleanest way might just be to have different routing set up, instead of the alternatives.

```
Route::post('/editProfileAvatar', [UserController::class, 'updateAvatar']);
Route::post('/editProfileBackground', [UserController::class, 'updateBGImage']);
```

Alternatively you could create a new method inside the controller that handles the logic as well, something like:

**route**

```
Route::post('/editProfile', [UserController::class, 'handleRequest']);
```

**controller**

```
public function handleRequest(Request $request) {
    
    //Handle the user upload of the avatar
    if($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
        return $this->updateAvatar($request);
    }
    
    //Handle the user upload of the background image
    if($request->hasFile('bgImage')) {
        return $this->updateBGImage($request);
    }
}
```

With the second example, you could then make the updateAvatar and updateBGImage methods private if you like,

Comment: With the second method the 'updateAvatar' function works but the 'bgImage' just returns a white page and it doesn't change the image.
And it's a pitty because it is really what i was looking for.
Because i'm trying to put everything inside the same form, so i can't use different routing links

Comment: I really have no way of troubleshooting that from my chair. Maybe you are also sending avatar in the request, but it is empty so it never reaches the second IF, maybe there is a php error but you have errors turned off. My answer is more of a proof of concept, since I have no way of viewing/debugging or understanding the rest of your application.